# Text overflowing out of Div When using transform: rotate(90.0deg)

Tags: html, css

here is my Work http://jsfiddle.net/2h8tv/

[image]

Here i am using css `transform: rotate(90.0deg)` . You can see the text coming out of the container. How can solve this without using padding or margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using `transform-origin` should be the most proper thing in this case. When you rotate an element with `transform: rotate(x)`, the rotation is done by a specific origin. By default, this origin is set to `50% 50%` which is the exact center of the element.
Add the following style to `.rotate` class

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 8px 12px;
```

However, you can make this rule more general:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 12px;
```

First part of the property is vertical position of the origin point. So in this case we set it to middle (50%). The second one defines horizontal position of the origin, so depending on parent div's width we should set it in *px*.

Comment: its also like padding. any way thanks, can u tellgetting me why this text is getting overflow

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. For me everything works fine. The whole text is visible.

Comment: Web transform origin is not like padding at all it sets the position of your rotation axis. Your issue is happending because you are rotating from the center point of you text, and because your text is longer than your box when rotating it overflows

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here, obviously just adding padding would be the easiest.

But you can also mess with the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/transform-origin) policy.

```
transform: rotate(90deg); transform-origin:8px 12px;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-ms-transform-origin:8px 12px /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin:8px 12px /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin:8px 12px /* Firefox */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin:8px 12px /* Opera */
```

See and example here http://jsfiddle.net/2h8tv/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **non-breaking Space** `&nbsp;`

```
<div class="orangeblock "><div class="rotate"> &nbsp;Free</div></div>
<div class="yelloblock"><div class="rotate"> &nbsp;$1999</div></div>
```

Check -> http://jsfiddle.net/2h8tv/1/

Comment: I don't know why the rotation get's messed up. But for a Solution without margin's and padding's this should cover you.

Comment: so if i use 2px font size i need to give more &nbsp; and for 15px 1 &nbsp

Comment: The best way is to use padding's but you stated that you not willing to add any.

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the font-size of `.rotate`. it will get aligned.

Comment: Suppose i want to use font size 9px, waht should do??

Comment: You can try giving line-height:40px. it gets aligned.